# Multiple object expression in With function VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a button in my Excel spreadsheet and I move the position of this button using the following VBA:

```
Sub Positioning_Button()
Set Range_Position = Sheet1.Range("D9:E11")
With Sheet1.Buttons("Button 1")
.Top = Range_Position.Top
.Left = Range_Position.Left
.Width = Range_Position.Width
.Height = Range_Position.Height
.Text = "Button"
End With
End Sub
```

All this works fine so far.

---

However, I also have a `Button 1` on `Sheet2` of the Excel file and I want to move this button the same way I do it for the button on `Sheet2`. One way to solve this issue is to make a second `Sub` in which I change `Sheet1` to `Sheet2`. 
 
However, I am wondering if there is more efficient solution in which I combine both sheets in the `With` function in the VBA. 
Something like this:

```
Sub Positioning_Button1()
Set Range_Position = Range("D9:E11")
With Sheet1.Buttons("Button 1") And Sheet2.Buttons("Button 1")
.Top = Range_Position.Top
.Left = Range_Position.Left
.Width = Range_Position.Width
.Height = Range_Position.Height
.Text = "Button"
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Will both sheet have only one button?

Comment: No, they could have more buttons. For example "Button 1" exist on both sheets but maybe on Sheet2 there is also a "Button 2" which should not be effected by the VBA at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paste this code in a **Module** and simply pass the button name to the `Sub Sample()`. Of course you may want to do do error handling to check if the right button name is sent to `MoveButton`.

```
Sub Sample()
    MoveButton "Button 1"
End Sub

Sub MoveButton(btnName As String)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Range_Position As Range

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set Range_Position = ws.Range("D9:E11")

    With ws.Buttons(btnName)
        .Top = Range_Position.Top
        .Left = Range_Position.Left
        .Width = Range_Position.Width
        .Height = Range_Position.Height
        .Text = "Button"
    End With
End Sub
```

The `Set ws = ActiveSheet` will take of the necessary sheet.

**However**, if you want to specify the sheet name as well then use this

```
Sub Sample()
    MoveButton Sheet1, "Button 1"
End Sub

Sub MoveButton(sh As Worksheet, btnName As String)
    Dim Range_Position As Range

    Set Range_Position = sh.Range("D9:E11")

    With sh.Buttons(btnName)
        .Top = Range_Position.Top
        .Left = Range_Position.Left
        .Width = Range_Position.Width
        .Height = Range_Position.Height
        .Text = "Button"
    End With
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

> Thanks a lot for your answer. It is almost doing what I want. The issue is that the Button 1 should be moved in both sheets (Sheet1 and Sheet2) no matter which one of those sheets is active. So if I am currently on Sheet1 and I run the VBA both in Sheet1 and Sheet2 it should be moved to Range D9:D11

You mean like this?

```
Sub Sample()
    MoveButton Sheet2, "Button 1", Sheet1
End Sub

Sub MoveButton(sh As Worksheet, btnName As String, Optional shB As Worksheet)
    Dim Range_Position As Range

    Set Range_Position = sh.Range("D9:E11")

    With sh.Buttons(btnName)
        .Top = Range_Position.Top
        .Left = Range_Position.Left
        .Width = Range_Position.Width
        .Height = Range_Position.Height
        .Text = "Button"
    End With

    If Not shB Is Nothing Then
        With shB.Buttons(btnName)
            .Top = Range_Position.Top
            .Left = Range_Position.Left
            .Width = Range_Position.Width
            .Height = Range_Position.Height
            .Text = "Button"
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

When you do not want to move a button in both sheets then use only

```
MoveButton Sheet2, "Button 1"
```

Do not specify the 3rd parameter which is optional.

Comment: Should probably be `With sh.Buttons(btnName)`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It is almost doing what I want. The issue is that the Button 1 should be moved in both sheets (Sheet1 and Sheet2) no matter which one of those sheets is active. So if I am currently on Sheet1 and I run the VBA both in Sheet1 and Sheet2 it should be moved to Range D9:D11

Comment: @Michi I have updated the post. Does it do what you want now? :)

Comment: Yeah. That is what I needed. However, another issue came up. Maybe you also have an idea for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59423765/multiple-object-expression-in-with-function-looping-through-all-sheets