# Multiple object expression in With function looping through all sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel spreadsheet consisting of two sheets (`Sheet1` and `Sheet2`).
In each sheet I have a `Button 1`. 
In order to move this button to `Range("D9:E11")` in both sheets I use the following VBA refering to the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59422100/multiple-object-expression-in-with-function-vba):

```
Sub Sample()
    MoveButton Sheet2, "Button 1", Sheet1
End Sub

Sub MoveButton(sh As Worksheet, btnName As String, Optional shB As Worksheet)
    Dim Range_Position As Range

    Set Range_Position = sh.Range("D9:E11")

    With sh.Buttons(btnName)
        .Top = Range_Position.Top
        .Left = Range_Position.Left
        .Width = Range_Position.Width
        .Height = Range_Position.Height
        .Text = "Button"
    End With

    If Not shB Is Nothing Then
        With shB.Buttons(btnName)
            .Top = Range_Position.Top
            .Left = Range_Position.Left
            .Width = Range_Position.Width
            .Height = Range_Position.Height
            .Text = "Button"
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

All this works perfectly so far.

---

However, now this Excel file will get bigger and instead of two sheets I will have much more sheets (for example 30 Sheets). In this case I would have to add all of those sheets to the `Sub Sample ()`.

What do I need to change in the code above to make it independent from the number of sheets so the button is moved to `Range("D9:D11")` in all sheets no matter how many sheets I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is pretty simple. Follow the same logic and declare a `Optional` boolean variable say, `AllSheets`.

```
Sub Sample()
    MoveButton Sheet1, "Button 1", True
End Sub

Sub MoveButton(sh As Worksheet, btnName As String, Optional AllSheets As Boolean)
    Dim Range_Position As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set Range_Position = sh.Range("D9:E11")

    If AllSheets = True Then
        For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
            With ws.Buttons(btnName)
                .Top = Range_Position.Top
                .Left = Range_Position.Left
                .Width = Range_Position.Width
                .Height = Range_Position.Height
                .Text = "Button"
            End With
        Next ws
    Else
        With sh.Buttons(btnName)
            .Top = Range_Position.Top
            .Left = Range_Position.Left
            .Width = Range_Position.Width
            .Height = Range_Position.Height
            .Text = "Button"
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: With the code I get runtime error 1004 on With ws.Buttons(btnName)

Comment: Maybe because there is no button with that name?

Comment: Debug the code and check what is the sheet name at the time of ereor

Comment: I found the issue. The reason was that there was one sheet without this Button 1. I am wondering if there is also way to just exclude this one sheet from the code.

Comment: Yes there is. Check whether that button exists or not before the line `With ws.Buttons(btnName)`. Give it a try and if you are stuck then post the code that you tried and we will take it from there?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support. I opened a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59425740/loop-to-move-buttons-in-excel-file-excluding-some-sheets