# Define sheets of MoveButton function in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file consisting of `5 Sheets`. 
In `Sheet1`, `Sheet2` and `Sheet3` I have a `Button 1`.

Once the user clicks on one of those buttons all `Button 1` should move from their current position to range `D9:E11`. 
No matter in which sheet the user clicks the button.

I tried to go with the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59422100/multiple-object-expression-in-with-function-vba) but it only works if I have two sheets. 
I tried to add `Sheet3` but it did not work:

> wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment

```
Sub Sample()
    MoveButton Sheet1, "Button 1", Sheet2, Sheet3
End Sub

Sub MoveButton(sh As Worksheet, btnName As String, Optional shB As Worksheet)
    Dim Range_Position As Range

    Set Range_Position = sh.Range("D9:E11")

    With sh.Buttons(btnName)
        .Top = Range_Position.Top
        .Left = Range_Position.Left
        .Width = Range_Position.Width
        .Height = Range_Position.Height
        .Text = "Button 1"
    End With

    If Not shB Is Nothing Then
        With shB.Buttons(btnName)
            .Top = Range_Position.Top
            .Left = Range_Position.Left
            .Width = Range_Position.Width
            .Height = Range_Position.Height
            .Text = "Button 1"
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

What do I need to change in the code to specify each sheet in which I want to move the `Button 1` to range `D9:E11`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The procedure as it is, just admits a maximum of three parameters.

```
MoveButton(sh As Worksheet, btnName As String, Optional shB As Worksheet)
```

Notice that the commas after MoveButton are currently separating the three parameters.

You can either change it or call it three times at least.

If you decide to modify the caller:

```
Sub Sample()
    MoveButton Sheet1, "Button 1", Sheet2
    MoveButton Sheet3, "Button 1", Sheet4
    MoveButton Sheet5, "Button 1"
End Sub
```

Rereading the question, if buttons are only in the mentioned sheets, use:

```
Sub Sample()
    MoveButton Sheet1, "Button 1", Sheet2
    MoveButton Sheet3, "Button 1"
End Sub
```